# logarithmic yScale on angularjs nvd3

Tags: angularjs, scale, nvd3.js

I would change the y-scale of my discreteBarChart to avoid huge gap (here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/63vOmB?p=preview)). On the [main page](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) of AngularJS nvd3 I saw the attribute `yScale`, and in several examples is set to

```
yScale: function i(n){return o(n)}
```

I don't know what means. I tried to change this function with `d3.scale.log` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularJS library for drawing bar charts with logarithmic scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376903/angularjs-library-for-drawing-bar-charts-with-logarithmic-scale)