# angularJS library for drawing bar charts with logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I'm looking for a free library (MIT License and compatible with angularJS) that allows me to draw BarChart setting some properties, in particular a logarithmic scale for axis (because I have a huge gap between values in the y-Axis). I tried with [angular-nvd3.js](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) but it doesn't allow to set the logarithmic scale. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with a little "trick": convert values in logarithmic values but show original values. In code (I use angular-nvd3.js):

```
<nvd3 options="options" data="myData"></nvd3>
```

This is the definition of chart in html. In the angular controller:

```
$scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'discreteBarChart',
            height: 250,
            width: 400,

            showXAxis: false,
            valueFormat: function (d) {
                return d3.format(',.3f')(d);
            },
            rightAlignYAxis: true,
            useInteractiveGuideline: false,
            tooltips: true,
            tooltipContent: function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
                return '<table> <tr> <td>' + x + ':</td><td> <b>' + (Math.pow(10,e.value)-1).toFixed(3) + '</b></td></tr></table>'
            },
            showYAxis: false,
            x: function (d) { return d.label; },
            y: function (d) {return d.value > 0 ? (Math.log(d.value + 1) / Math.LN10) : 0 },
            color: ['#4682B4']
        }
    };
```

In this way I solved the problem of huge gap between values (thank to `Math.log`) without losing original values (thanks to `Math.pow`), the only ones that will be shown to the end user.